# some file system operations very slow, ssd

Tags: finder, ssd, filesystem, file-transfer, archive

(macbook air 2012, noticed before I upgraded to mavericks)

on my SSD, newly downloaded files or newly created folders take a very long time to be moved, viewed, or examined. I have 1/5th of the free space available.

I also notice this after I extract an archive file, and try to look at its new folder, it takes upwards of 5 minutes before the file listing will return, in finder.

this concerns me as I have an incomplete backup, what is going on and how can I improve it?

Comment: Have you examined Activity Monitor.app to see if there is anything using a lot of RAM or CPU? How frequently to you shut your system down and is everything on your computer up-to-date?

Comment: @AndrewU. nothing is using an abnormal amount of RAM or CPU, yet, an I/O operation would have nothing to do with that. I shut my system down maybe a few times a year, mainly system updates, but I haven't updated to 10.9.2, also not a solution unless it contains a fix specific for this issue which we have yet to identify

Comment: I suggest to sign in with Guest Account and try to replicate the problem. It’ll help you to decide if it’s the OS level problem, or caused by third party apps.

Comment: Well how about you test a restart and see if it helps...